# Why does a name error appear? adv_fml_lopez de prado. python 3.7 colab

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading

```
def getTEvents(gRaw, h):
    tEvents, sPos, sNeg = [], 0, 0
    diff = np.log(gRaw).diff().dropna()
    for i in tqdm(diff.index[1:]):
        try:
            pos, neg = float(sPos+diff.loc[i]), float(sNeg+diff.loc[i])
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            print (sPos+diff.loc[i], type(sPos+diff.loc[i]))
            print(sNeg+diff.loc[i], type(sNeg+diff.loc[i]))
            break
        sPos, sNeg=max(0., pos), min(0., neg)
        if sNeg<-h:
            sNeg=0;tEvents.append(i)
        elif sPos>h:
            sPos=0;tEvents.append(i)
    return pd.DatetimeIndex(tEvents)       

getTEvents(df0['Close'], 10000) #
```

Name Error: tdqm not defined

I don't understand what tdqm is either and where the cusum is done.

Answer (score 4):

`tqdm` is a simple package for progress bars in Python. I am not familiar with the code you have copy pasted but most likely you haven't installed `tqdm` on your machine. You can find more documentation [here](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) (a quick google search would have revealed this as well). To fix your issue, you can run `pip install tqdm` in `cmd` and then import the package in your Python script via `from tqdm import tqdm`.